# ORA-01031 Insufficient Privileges Raised From Within Function

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-sql-developer

When I run a `CREATE USER` statement within Sql Developer, the user is created just fine.  When I try to call a function which performs `CREATE USER` (followed by a bunch of other statements) I get the ORA-01031 error when that statement is executed.  On another machine this function is apparently completing successfully.  I have checked all the roles and system privileges but nothing stands out.  What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have permission to perform an action at the command line but not within a definer's rights stored procedure (and I hope you're using a stored procedure here, not a stored function), the problem is almost certainly that the privilege you need has been granted through a role, not directly to the user that owns the procedure.  Inside a definer's rights stored procedure, only privileges that have been granted directly to the owner of the procedure can be used-- privileges granted through a role (such as `DBA`) cannot be used.

You can verify that the problem is, in fact, that the privilege is granted through a role by disabling roles and then trying to create the user, i.e.

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> create user ...
```

Assuming that fails, as I expect it will, you would need to grant the owner of the function the `CREATE USER` privilege directly

```
SQL> grant create user to <<owner of procedure>>
```

Then, you should be able to create users even with roles disabled and the stored procedure should work.

Comment: I am going to go bang my head against a sufficiently thick block of concrete.  I just had the owner of the procedure incorrect ... I was assuming it was someone else.  Granting to the correct user solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I got bit by this for a different reason (different situation) but similar... I had granted UPDATE and READ to a table in the procedure that it was updating, but changed the  privilege from READ to SELECT and the error went away.  I suppose due to READ not having `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` abilities.